# Discord bot runs locally but not on EC2 server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, discord, discord.py

So I can run my bot locally from my machine and it works great, but when I try to host it on an AWS I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Here's the line that's causing the problem.

```
role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=entered_role)
```

Comment: What version of [tag:discord.py] is the target box running?  Try executing `python3 -c "import discord; print(discord.__version__)"`.

Comment: version 1.0.0a.

Comment: Your code is built for version 0.16 (the "async" branch), while your computer is running version `1.0` (the "rewrite" branch).  You can either change the version on the computer or update your code (you should probably update your code).  [The docs for the rewrite version](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html) are probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Like Patrick said in the comments, my bot was written using the wrong API version. Updating it to the newer version solved the problem.